# How to merge or groupBy toPromise via RxJs?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have the following method that returns result as shown below:

```
result: [ { status: 200, ... }, { status: 200, ... }, { status: 400, ... }, ... ]
```

I need to group the result by using status value and return only 2 results instead of 3 for the example result above:

```
update() {
  this.demoService.update(...).toPromise()
  .then(result => {

    const message = result.map((x: any) => {
      if (x.status === 200) {
        return {
          text: 'successful'
        };
      } else {
        return {
          text: 'fail'
        };
      }
    });

    }
  })
}
```

I tried to use `groupBy` of RxJs but I think it cannot be used in Promise. So, how can I group this result in the example above?

Comment: Why do you even use a `Promise`? You can use `groupBy()` when piping the observable:  `this.demoService.update(...).pipe(groupBy())`

Comment: Yes, but I am wondering if there is a possibility to use groupBy in toPromise?

Comment: You cannot use RxJs Operators there. But you can achieve it with normal mapping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects

Comment: `groupBy` is a `RxJs` operator and can be used only inside `pipe()`: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/groupby. Do you need to print only distinct status codes?

Comment: @DonJuwe Which one do you mean in that example? could you please post the one you refer to the update method in my question and post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it works, but you can try (*you filter only entities with distinct status, then select only statuses*):

```
update() {
  this.demoService.update(...).subscribe(result => {
    const messages = result
        .filter((x, i, arr) => arr.findIndex(t => t.status === x.status) === i)
        .map(x => x.status);

    // do stuff
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom grouping method like this:

```js
var groupBy = (xs, key) => {
  return xs.reduce((rv, x) => {
    (rv[x[key]] = rv[x[key]] || []).push(x);
    return rv;
  }, {});
};

console.log(groupBy([{status: 200, foo: 'bar'}, {status: 200, foo: 'baz'}, {status: 400, foo: 'bar'}], 'status'));
```

Output:

```
{
    "200": [
        {
            "status": 200,
            "foo": "bar"
        },
        {
            "status": 200,
            "foo": "baz"
        }
    ],
    "400": [
        {
            "status": 400,
            "foo": "bar"
        }
    ]
}
```